# change background-color of link collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the background-color of link collapse, but its not working.

why?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <a id="aa" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" onclick="$(this).css('background-color','#ececec')">
 <div>
 click here
 </div>
 </a>
```

Comment: link collapse means what?

Comment: You are using jQuery have you intialized document.ready method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work the `a` element needs to be set to either `display: inline-block` or `display: block`:

```css
a { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="aa" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" onclick="$(this).css('background-color', '#ececec')">
  <div>
    click here
  </div>
</a>
```

That being said, you should not use `on*` event attributes at all. Use unobtrusive JS to attach your event handlers instead. The use of `css()` should also be avoided too, in favour of adding CSS classes defined in a stylesheet. Try this:

```js
$('#aa').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
a { display: inline-block; }
a.active { background-color: #ECECEC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="aa" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
  <div>
    click here
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a separate file :

```
$(function(){

  $('a[data-toggle=collapse]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add `display:block` like following

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <a id="aa" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" onclick="$(this).css({'background-color':'#ececec', 'display':'block'})">
 <div>
 click here
 </div>
 </a>
```